# How To bind Limit Record in DataGrid UWP?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

how will we do this binding in Data Grid ,i have 30 Record but i want to bind only 10 record .i am taking all value to collection List class in c# .thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq. For example:

```
List<Product> datasource = db.TakeAllProducts();
List<Product> first10 = datasource.Take(10).ToList();
this.datagrid.DataSource = first10;
```

Comment: hi ,Thank You Very much ,now i binding only 10 record in DataGrid with help for you ,Have a nice day

Comment: but when i click next button is not geting ahead 10 record still is bind exiting 10 record only not move to another  record?

Comment: Ah ok, you need pagination

Answer (score 0):

To implement the pagination, you can follow the following steps:

1. Define three variables globally in your page:

   ```
   //define how many pages totally accroding to calculation.
   int pageCount;
   //define current page number.
   int currentPage;
   //define how many items you want to show in page.
   int countPerPage;
   ```
2. Initiate them during page loading:

   ```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       countPerPage = 10;
       float tmpFloat = (float)myList.Count / countPerPage;
       pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(tmpFloat);
       currentPage = 1;
       ManageButton();//manage the buttons' disable
       myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList.GetRange(0, countPerPage);
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Calculate which items to show through the following method(I'm using [List.GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the list):

   ```
   private List<String> GetList(List<String> sourceList)
   {
       int index = (currentPage - 1) * countPerPage;
       int countsToShow;
       if (currentPage == pageCount)
       {
           countsToShow = myList.Count - (currentPage - 1) * countPerPage;
       }
       else
       {
           countsToShow = countPerPage;
       }
       return sourceList.GetRange(index, countsToShow);
   }
   ```
4. In your previsou button or next button's click event, handle the Data Grid's items refresh. Also don't forget to enable or disable the buttons when current page has hit the boundary(through ManageButton method).

   ```
   private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       currentPage--;
       ManageButton();
       myDataGrid.ItemsSource = GetList(myList);
   }

   private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       currentPage++;
       ManageButton();
       myDataGrid.ItemsSource = GetList(myList);
   }

   private void ManageButton()
   {
       if (currentPage <= 1)
       {
           btnPrevious.IsEnabled = false;
           btnNext.IsEnabled = true;
       }
       else if (currentPage >= pageCount)
       {
           btnPrevious.IsEnabled = true;
           btnNext.IsEnabled = false;
       }
       else
       {
           btnPrevious.IsEnabled = true;
           btnNext.IsEnabled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

Here is my complete demo: [Pagination](https://github.com/elvisxia/Pagination).

Comment: Thank You Very Much Have nice day:-)